# IE8 - Problem with Hyperlink that wraps image and div

Tags: jquery, html

Im having issues with the following HTML in IE8:

```
<div class="inner">
    <a href="google.com" target="_self">
        <div class="lozbutton">
            <img alt="OPENHIVE Survey" src="http://url.com/product" />
        </div>
        <div class="description">&nbsp;</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

When clicking on the `.description` div the hyperlink works, however when ever I click on the `<img>` the link doesnt work.

Can anyone suggest how I can make both the `<img>` and the `.description` div link to the same place? either HTML fix or jQuery fix.

Comment: This is invalid markup and will cause problems: You can't have a block level element inside a link. 

Try using inline elements

Comment: The problem is not within this part of the code that you have provided even if Pekka is right. Better give URL where you have this problem. And change div with span.

Comment: @Pekka It's not invalid HTML5 markup: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: @robertc that is good to know, thanks for the link. But it's invalid in HTML 4.

Comment: @Pekka I know it's not invalid HTML4, but there's not enough information in the question to determine which is more appropriate in this case ;)  Either way, we have evidence that wrapping block level elements in links works, so it seems likely Yasen Zhelev is correct and the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I've found to have this work in IE8 or IE9 is to add an HTML5 doctype declaration to the top of the file:

```
<!doctype html>
```

This causes the browser to interpret the file as HTML5, in which case it behaves appropriately.